# Should I assign parameter values to local variables first instead of using them directly?

Tags: c#

Is there any reason to assign parameter values to local variables inside a method in order to use those values **without changing them**? I.e. like the following:

```
private void MyMethod(string path)
{
    string myPath = path;
    StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(myPath);
    ...
}
```

Or can I always put it like this (and the code above is redundant and just not clean):

```
private void MyMethod(string path)
{
    StreamReader mystream = new StreamReader(path);
    ...
}
```

I know it works both ways, but I'd like to be sure there isn't anything I missed in my understanding.

Comment: Assuming that variable isn't used elsewhere, the only reason for the first case I can see is to aide with debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same thing, the only difference is that in the first case you make a copy of the reference (which is destroyed anyway when the method gets out of scope, which happens when the execution ends).

For better readability, stick with the second case.

Comment: Please note this is not always the best case.  In some cases this can cause issues depending on how the variable is used.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 4):

The only time you need to do this (assign locally) is if you are in a foreach loop or using Linq.  Otherwise you can run into issues with modified closures.

Here is a snippet from an MSDN blog (All content below is from the link).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

But I'm getting ahead of myself. What's the output of this fragment?

```
var values = new List<int>() { 100, 110, 120 };
var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
foreach(var v in values) 
  funcs.Add( ()=>v );
foreach(var f in funcs) 
  Console.WriteLine(f());
```

Most people expect it to be 100 / 110 / 120.  It is in fact 120 / 120 / 120. Why?

Because ()=>v means "return the current value of variable v", not "return the value v was back when the delegate was created". Closures close over variables, not over values. And when the methods run, clearly the last value that was assigned to v was 120, so it still has that value.

This is very confusing. The correct way to write the code is:

```
foreach(var v in values) 
{
  var v2 = v;
  funcs.Add( ()=>v2 );
}
```

Now what happens? Every time we re-start the loop body, we logically create a fresh new variable v2. Each closure is closed over a different v2, which is only assigned to once, so it always keeps the correct value.

Basically, the problem arises because we specify that the foreach loop is a syntactic sugar for

```
 {
    IEnumerator<int> e = ((IEnumerable<int>)values).GetEnumerator();
    try
    { 
      int m; // OUTSIDE THE ACTUAL LOOP
      while(e.MoveNext())
      {
        m = (int)(int)e.Current;
        funcs.Add(()=>m);
      }
    }
    finally
    { 
      if (e != null) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
    }
  }
```

If we specified that the expansion was

```
try
{ 
  while(e.MoveNext())
  {
    int m; // INSIDE
    m = (int)(int)e.Current;
    funcs.Add(()=>m);
  }
```

then the code would behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second option. It makes no sense to create a new variable with the parameter. Also, from a reading perspective, it makes more sense to create a stream from a path (the one you received) instead of instantiating a "myPath" variable.